# Hide the menu bar for Microsoft Remote Desktop for MAC full screen mode

Tags: macos, fullscreen, rdp

My MAC book OS version is macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.4.  For Microsoft RDP client, when I switch to full screen mode, the menu bar still occupies the top space. Even it's auto-hidden. That cause the scrollbar displayed in the remote desktop.

This issue only happens when I display the remote desktop in the external monitor. There's no problem when show on native MAC Book LCD display.

How to remote the un-necessary menu bar space?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the preferences for the connection and try setting the RDP session screen resolution to a lower setting.  I suspect the setting is higher than your Macbook resolution forcing the scroll bar.

Comment: In fullscreen mode, I select resolution as "Native", it should automatically match the actual screen resolution. And the same setting works well in build in LCD display. Problem only happens in external display.

Comment: I've noticed the difference between the built in retina resolution and external display resolution (lower) can cause some odd behaviors.